# Why is pyforms unable to import conf from pysettings

Tags: python-3.x

I want to use pyforms to prepare a simple python based program and have been trying to install and use it with no luck.

When I run:

```
import pyforms
from   pyforms          import BaseWidget
from   pyforms.Controls import ControlText
from   pyforms.Controls import ControlButton
```

All I get is a Traceback error in the terminal and:

```
from pysettings import conf;
ImportError: cannot import name 'conf'
```

I'm using pysettings 1.90 and pyforms 0.1.7.3

I've uninstalled and reinstalled several times with no luck and have been using python3.4.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Please include full traceback and links to all 3rd party libraries used.

Comment: Sorry,  Traceback:

Comment: Sorry cant make the formatting better!,  Traceback:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Programming\pyforms3.py", line 2 in <module>
    import pyforms
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pyforms\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from pysettings import conf;
    ImportError: cannot import name 'conf' `


links:pyforms [link](http://pyforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
pysettings [link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PySettings)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pyforms cannot import conf from pysettings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41216740/pyforms-cannot-import-conf-from-pysettings)

Answer (score 2):

You will need to download and install pysettings from https://github.com/UmSenhorQualquer/pysettings/tree/92bde8c680bc0a00ae97cc09bd4dab1b697d6ed2

The original pysettings will not work.