# pyforms cannot import conf from pysettings

Tags: python, python-2.x, importerror, pyforms

This is my python file:

```
import pyforms
import pyside
from   pyforms          import BaseWidget
from   pyforms.Controls import ControlText
from   pyforms.Controls import ControlButton

class SimpleExample1(BaseWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(SimpleExample1,self).__init__('Simple example 1')

        #Definition of the forms fields
        self._firstname     = ControlText('First name', 'Default value')
        self._middlename    = ControlText('Middle name')
        self._lastname      = ControlText('Lastname name')
        self._fullname      = ControlText('Full name')
        self._button        = ControlButton('Press this button')

        #Define the button action
        self._button.value = self.__buttonAction

    def __buttonAction(self):
        """Button action event"""
        self._fullname.value = self._firstname.value +" "+ self._middlename.value + \
        " "+ self._lastname.value

#Execute the application
if __name__ == "__main__":

    pyforms.startApp( SimpleExample1 )
```

And I got an error in the `__init__.py` file:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\Ashish\pyforms\1.py", line 1, in <module>
import pyforms
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyforms\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
from pysettings import conf;
ImportError: No module named pysettings
```

Here is my `__init__.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import logging 
from pysettings import conf;

conf += 'pyforms.gui.settings'

__author__ = "Ricardo Ribeiro"
__credits__ = ["Ricardo Ribeiro"]
__license__ = "MIT"
__version__ = '0.1.7.3'
__maintainer__ = "Ricardo Ribeiro"
__email__ = "ricardojvr@gmail.com"
__status__ = "Production"

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

if conf.PYFORMS_MODE in ['GUI', 'GUI-OPENCSP']:

    from pyforms.gui import Controls
    from pyforms.gui.BaseWidget import BaseWidget

    if conf.PYFORMS_MODE in ['GUI-OPENCSP']:
        from pyforms.gui.appmanager import startApp
    else:
        from pyforms.gui.standaloneManager import startApp

elif conf.PYFORMS_MODE in ['TERMINAL']:

    from pyforms.terminal import Controls
    from pyforms.terminal.BaseWidget import BaseWidget
    from pyforms.terminal.appmanager import startApp    

elif conf.PYFORMS_MODE in ['WEB']:

    from pyforms_web.web import Controls
    from pyforms_web.web.BaseWidget import BaseWidget
    from pyforms_web.web.appmanager import startApp
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to download and install pysettings from https://github.com/UmSenhorQualquer/pysettings/tree/92bde8c680bc0a00ae97cc09bd4dab1b697d6ed2

Comment: Thank you so much u made my day